# scipy.integrate.ode ignores boundary conditions

Tags: pde, python, time-integration, scipy

I am trying to solve the 1-dimensional diffusion problem numerically using method of lines:

$$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} =D \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial z^2},$$

where the right hand side is discretised and the left hand side is handled with a standard ode solver.

I have two boundary conditions. One boundary condition dynamically changes with every timestep (`dcdt[0]`), while the other is always fixed at a constant value (`dcdt[-1]`). There is also one initial condition (concentration profile) at time zero, which is the line in dark blue in the picture shown.

Unfortunately, what happens is that `scipy.integrate.ode` ignores both boundary conditions!

[image: Output]

```
def diffusion(t,c, h):
    dcdt = zeros(Nz)
    dcdt[0] = funcA(h)
    dcdt[-1] = B # a constant    
    for i in range(1,Nz-1):
        dcdt[i] = D * (c[i+1] - 2*c[i] + c[i-1]) / (dz*dz) 

    return dcdt
```

I use `scipy.integrate.ode` to integrate the discretisation equation. I have defined the `diffusion` function to set the boundary condition every time the `ode(diffusion)` is called.

```
ode = integrate.ode(diffusion).set_integrator('vode')
ode.set_initial_value(c_initial, 0).set_f_params(h0)
k = 0

while ode.successful() and k < Nt:
    dcdz = (y[1] - y[0]) / dz
    h[k] = h[k-1] + Q*(h[k-1]**2) / func(h[k-1]) * dt * dcdz
    c_out[:,k] = ode.y
    t[k] = ode.t

    ode.set_f_params(h[k]) # Change the b.c.
    ode.integrate(ode.t + dt)
    k += 1
```

I have checked the following things:

- By inserting `print h` into the `diffusion` function I have checked that `set_f_params` has successfully passed `h` into the solver.
- There are no numerical instabilities. I have also checked other solvers `dopri5`, stiff/non-stiff options, etc.
- I have switched the order of functions in the while loop around. It seems that the problem is internal, i.e. `ode.integrate(ode.t + dt)` solves the equation and ignores the boundary conditions I want to impose before returning the output to me. I'm puzzled why it would do that.
- One thing I have thought about is that I could use `set_initial_value` to set the boundary condition. But as far as I know, I have to provide a full solution vector $c(z,t)$ at a certain time, and `ode.integrate` is already ignoring my boundary condition at time zero.

Comment: Have you tried only solving for the interior nodes (i.e., don't solve the ode at $z=0$ and $z=1$ and use the boundary conditions as explicit values in the finite difference)?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but wouldn't $\partial c(t,1)/\partial t=B$ lead to $c(t,1) = c(0,1) + Bt$, increasing linearly, just as in the plot? Is $B=0$ or $\partial B/\partial t=0$? Do you get the right boundary conditions if you set $D=0$, in effect solving two uncoupled ODEs?

Comment: I would check running your code, but there is not enough pieces of it to run.

Comment: Please write down the precise boundary conditions.